# Google Cloud API batching topic creation in python

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

We are trying to batch different topic creation calls (tens to hundreds) to Google Cloud PubSub using the Google Cloud API. It's unclear how we can do this.

Currently, we have the following, but we cannot seem to find documentation on how to inject the create topic request in the batch call. Does anyone have insights in how to do this?

```
api = build('pubsub', 'v1')
batch = api.new_batch_http_request(callback=foo)

publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()

for topic_name in [.....]:
  topic_path = publisher.topic_path('my-project-id', topic_name)
  request = ???.create_topic(topic_path)
  batch.add(request)

batch.execute()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you try to achieve 2 different things

- Perform a batch request, which mean publish a bulk of message in only one request. For this, you use the discovery API. [Standard library](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher#batching) exists for this if you prefer
- Create a PubSub topic. This is another API call. You can still use discovery API, or the [standard library](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/admin#creating_a_topic)

With this you could achieve what you want.

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping to batch create topic requests, but apparently, that is not possible :( I'll clarify my question a bit.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to batch create topic requests. Each call to create topic must be done individually:

```
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1

project_id = "Your Google Cloud Project ID"
topic_name = "Your Pub/Sub topic name"

publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()
topic_path = publisher.topic_path(project_id, topic_name)

topic = publisher.create_topic(topic_path)

print('Topic created: {}'.format(topic))
```

This will create a single topic and so this logic must be repeated for each topic you wish to create.

The only batching Cloud Pub/Sub offers is in the publishing of messages. The client library handles this and the size of the batches is controlled by the [BatchSettings](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/pubsub/publisher/index.html#batching). For example, the following code would batch up to 10 messages together, assuming `messages` contains a list of messages to be published.

```
from google.cloud import pubsub
from google.cloud.pubsub import types

client = pubsub.PublisherClient(
  batch_settings=types.BatchSettings(max_messages=10),
)

def callback(future):
  message_id = future.result()
  print('Message published {}'.format(message_id))

for m in messages:
  future = client.publish(topic, m)
  future.add_done_callback(callback)
```